# Correct way to build and run GridDB SpringBoot Web API

Tags: griddb

I have cloned the SpringBoot GridDB web API project from GitHub and I am trying to build it as specified in their Readme.md file. However, I just realized that the project was set up to run on Java 10 and gradle 4.9 because I got an error suggesting that I use Java 10 as I was using my default Java version , and the build was breaking. The problem is, even after installing Java 10, the project still fails to build suggesting that a daemon cannot be reused. All research that I have done suggests that the configuration might have an issue. Has anyone successfully built it and is there something that can be done to make it a maven project? Thank you
[image]